# Package mhchem Gives an Error

Tags: errors, mhchem

I recently tried to use `mhchem` and it works for some commands, but not for some. Here is a sample code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
  \ce{X-X}
  \ce{C\bond{~-}C}
\end{document}
```

Gives me

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\mhchem@bond #1->\ifnum \pdf@strcmp 
                                    {#1}{-}=0\sbond \else \ifnum \pdf@strcmp...
l.7   \ce{C\bond{~-}C}
```

I followed the `mhchem` manual and I cannot seem to find a mistake. I installed this package on 2/8/2015 so I should be running the latest version. Any ideas on this one?

Comment: I am using MiKTex 2.9 latex distribution. It works normally!!!

Comment: @OLSAY Me, too, but I get the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in `mhchem`, which doesn't either define the command `\pdf@strcmp` or load the package `pdftexcmds` explicitly, where it is defined, but relies on the driver code (`graphics.cfg`) to load it.

The bug can be seen when using MiKTeX with pdfLaTeX or XeTeX (not LuaLateX). When using TeX Live it can be noticed compiling with XeTeX.

As a workaround, it should suffice to load this package

```
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\usepackage{pdftexcmds}    

\begin{document}
  \ce{X-X}
  \ce{C\bond{~-}C}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: I have reported this issue to the package maintainer.

Comment: This is the maintainer of mhchem. Thanks for investigating and reporting. I fixed the issue and uploaded version 3.19 (2015-02-09) to CTAN. It should make its way to your preferred mirror within 48 hours.

Comment: It works, thank you!
Another computer I had and so do ShareLaTeX did compile the code normally.

Answer (score 0):

For a local texlive installation from 2015 dvd, none of the method described above worked for me. From a [thread](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41/2015/8/31/4-24), I learned that it was a bug in mhchem.

> @Joseph ah sorry, it's `mhchem` that seems to cause it, not `siunitx`, but still, it looks to me like some L3 incompatibility -- I surely don't define `\c_backslash_str` myself... Ok, putting `\RequirePackage{mhchem}` before `\documentclass` seems to have solved it.

I followed the instruction to add `\RequirePackage{mhchem}` before `\documentclass` and now the problem is solved.

Comment: An update of your TeX distribution would be a better solution